# Can we use WPF controls in ASP.NET web application Projects?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use WPF Controls in our ASP.Net Project? Since WPF has enriched and new featured controls .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use  WPF Controls in ASP.Net Project because they are two different technologies. There is a [Microsoft SilverLight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/), which is made for this purposes.

WPF exists as a subset of .NET Framework types that are for the most part located in the System.Windows namespace and used for creating of standalone applications. It like the next generation of winForms. Asp.Net is used to make the web applications, based on System.Web Namespace. Microsoft created the technology, named SilverLight, which is some kind of plugin for web applications for integrating the WPF functionality into you page.